# Efficiency of serialization of object to indexedDB verus JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, indexeddb

I'm interested in the difference in terms of efficiency for browser/CPU/memory between the serialization step of JSON.stringify versus that of writing an object to an object store in indexedDB.

The motivation or context for the question is writing an object from the database to the client's hard drive in the most efficient manner. To do so, the object is retrieved with a get statement and written to an object, that object is converted to a string with JSON.stringify and then written as text to disk. I assume that the get statement unserializes the object from its serialized form in the database.  If so, then the object is unserialized from indexedDB form and then serialized to JSON.stringify form.

Then to recover the data from disk, the file is read, the text is converted to an object with JSON.parse and the object is added or put in the database, which appears to require another serialization step. So, the JSON string is parsed to an object and then serialized to the indexedDB form.

The first part of my question is can the object be retrieved from the database in its serialized form so that it can be saved to disk in that same form and again written to the database without having to perform the intermediate steps of stringify/parse?

The second part of the question is, if it is not possible to do so, and for the special case of using indexedDB without any indexing and never querying data by any value other than an out-of-line unique key, is there any advantage to storing the stringified object to the database rather than the object?

In this scenario, the writing/reading to disk would not involve the intermediate stringify/parse steps and there would be no unserialization/serialization step when the string is get/put in the database since it is not an object. However, to change a value in one of these strings in the database would require a JSON.parse on the result of get to convert it to an object and then a JSON.stringify after the value is changed before the string is put back in the database.

But how do the JSON.parse and JSON.stringify compare to the unserialization and reserialization of the database object when using get and put on the object? I thought that the serialization of an object to indexedDB would require more than a JSON.stringify, since the former can be queried by its properties.

I will experiment to see if a difference is observable, but wanted to ask someone who understands the inner workings of the two types of serialization if there is an underlying reason, in this case, to use one approach over the other.

**EDIT**

Apparently, if I understand correctly, the structured clone algorithm is used in storing objects in indexedDB; but is that result still serialized before storing? and JSON employs a lexical grammer but never copies the object.

Perhaps, I'm just very confused and there is no serialization step in writing to indexedDB and the increased usage of RAM that I observed is to clone the object, which is then stored as an object.  If so, then the first part of question makes no sense at all, because the database object will always need to be converted to a string to save to disk. And the second part of my question would become which is more demanding on the browser, 1) converting an object to a string or cloning it and 2) retrieving and object from database versus retrieving a string (if saved as JSON string) and parsing it?

After finding more information about this, although much of it was over my head, I'm not sure the question is even worth considering.

Thank you.

**EXAMPLE:**

@Sam152 Are you saying that you have found that, in something like below, the stingify version is faster than just putting the object in the database? One example, is an interval of fifty transactions and the second is fifty `put` in a single transactions.

```
// var o = A large object.
var d;
write.x = 0;
write.y=[];

DB_open().then( inter );

function inter() { d = setInterval( write, 1000 ); }

function write()
  {
    let T = DB_open.base.transaction( [ 'os_name' ], 'readwrite' ),
        q = T.objectStore( 'os_name' ),
        start = Date.now();  

    T.oncomplete = function() { write.y.push( Date.now() - start ); }

    if ( write.x < 50 )
      write.x = write.x + 1;
    else
      {
        clearInterval(d);
        console.log( 'done' );
      };

    o.key = write.x;
    q.put( o );

    // OR

    q.put( { 'key' : write.x, 'd' : JSON.stringify( o ) } ); 

  } // close write

  // When complete.

  total = 0;
  write.y.forEach( ( v ) => { total = total + v; } );
```

Or, multiple `put` statement in the same transaction.

```
function write()

  {
    let T = DB_open.base.transaction( [ 'os_name' ], 'readwrite' ),
        q = T.objectStore( 'os_name' ),
        start = Date.now(),
        i;  

    T.oncomplete = function() 
      { console.log( 'Completed : ' + ( Date.now() - start ) ); }

    for ( i = 1; i < 51; i++ )
      {
        o.key = i;
        q.put( o );

        // OR

        q.put( { 'key' : i, 'd' : JSON.stringify( o ) } ); 
      };
  } // close write
```

Comment: > I thought that the serialization of an object to indexedDB would require more than a JSON.stringify, since the former can be queried by its properties.
---
I think this is a really valid question and I'm not observing the conclusions stated in the accepted answer at all. I'm finding that converting a large object to a string before inserting into indexdb is in the order of 10x times faster than inserting the plain object and I'm struggling to understand why.

I was wondering if there was any mechanism for inserting an object, but not performing any kind of indexing operation.

Comment: @Sam152 This may sound a bit strange but when I asked this question I was experimenting with various parts of browser functionality in indexedDB and extension APIs to determine if a project I was considering could be built in a browser.  It appeared that it could be and I've since been attempting to build out and assemble my experimental components.  I haven't returned to this step yet but will likely in the next month or so; thus, it is quite timely and interesting that someone would comment on the question after all this time.

Comment: @Sam152 I'm not a professional programmer so my comments aren't worth much and it's dificult to describe without explaining the entire process, but in my experimenting I found that holding all the records of an object store as a single JSON string, and then unpacking it into individual records in a different object store when needed and packing them back up when complete, made writng to disk much quicker.  My project allowed for holding big blocks of data as string until needed and that was always quicker when extracting the database to a blob and writing to disk.

Comment: @Sam152 I added a small example to ask if this is at all similar to what you're speaking about and to ask what exactly you mean by a large object.  Is it just large in size or in complexity, such as properties the values of which are objects and so on, that some refer to as nested?

Comment: Hi Gary, yep, pretty much what I observed. In my case, I am storing an object that when JSON encoded is roughly 40mb. I think your hypothesis that these objects are designed to be queried is responsible for the large difference in time, but it's just a hunch. In my case, I'm abusing the fact that indexDB can store a much larger object than localstorage, but I don't care about any of the querying semantics. 

I haven't found any info to suggest indexDB can be instructed to speed up read/writes at the expense of it's other features.

Comment: @Sam152 Are you using an inline key? I'm not entirely sure but from the description at `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB` under the heading `Structuring the datatabse`, it would appear that if you do not use an inline key, that is the No-Noand No-Yes rows in that lttle table, then you can save any data type not just JSON data. Perhaps in these two cases, the object will be saved closer to as is.

Comment: @Sam152 When I first tried this, I couldn't figure out how to use a key that is not inline because that isn't mentioned in the above document; but it is mentioned in the document for the `add` method, and is simply `objectStore.add(value, key)` rather than `objectStore.add(value)` where the `key` is provided separately rather than inline in the value object. I think in this case, you would be treating your object more like a blob or an image than an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no performance benefit to converting an object to a string and storing strings in the database. Converting an object to a string using JSON.stringify *only* adds to the number of steps that must occur. I would highly recommend not doing this, not even trying to do this, and not attempting to outsmart the indexedDB implementation in C++.

indexedDB serialization takes place in C++, not js. JSON.stringify takes place in js, not C++. Most of the time, anything that takes place in js is orders of magnitude slower than C++.

A js string is a js object. If I recall correctly, you cannot store a string as an object in indexedDB because it itself is a function-object, not a plain object. Another way of stating this is to think about the object type hierarchy. Everything extends from `Object`. `Function` extends from object. `String` extends from `Function` (well, maybe not directly nor explicitly, but nevertheless effectively). Any descendant that extends from `Function`, such as anything created using `class Foo` or `function Foo() {}; new Foo();` or `new Function('foo');`, is not serializable. Anything that extends from `Object` without extending from `Function` is serializable.

Functions are not serializable as explained in my answer to your other question.

When you create a js object using *object literal* syntax, this is merely syntactic sugar approximately for `new Object()`, not `function Foo()`. Such objects are easily serializable because they are basically just dictionaries. That is, up until the point you attach a method. A method again is nothing more than a function that is bound as a property to an object. Because even a plain object with at least one method is no longer serializable.

Instead of trying to store a string directly in indexedDB as itself is an object (a descendant of `Function`), you can only store the string as a property of some other object that is not a function object, because indexedDB has express knowledge of the String type and expressly claims support for storing object properties with string values, because it knows how to coerce such values during serialization.

The structured clone algorithm was renamed some time ago. It is now the serialization algorithm or something like the 'transferable' algorithm, I forget.

When you store an object in indexedDB (e.g. `{x:1,y:2}`) it will be sent from JS to C++, and then *within C++* it will be serialized. When you retrieve an object from indexedDB, then in C++ it will find the object in its serial form, deserialize it, then pass it to JS, and then JS passes it back to you (your function or return value whatever). Although serialization more specifically refers to the conversion of another type to a string, you can also use it more generically to refer to both directions, so keep that in mind, that serialization mentioned anywhere in tech docs may be actually talking about deserialization.

This C++ serialization is not necessarily from an object to a string or a string to an object, but to some optimized byte format. In C++ land it is sometimes less useful to differentiate between strings and other value types because a string is simply one arbitrary representation of bytes. So when we talk about serialization in C++ we are just talking about changing the representation of an abstract group of bytes. Much like how a struct in C is just a representation of a sequence of bytes broken into parts. In some sense, in C++ a string can be understood as a zero-cost abstraction depending on how it is used. In fact calling some group of bytes one type or another really only serves to clarify what operations should be called on those bytes, and how those bytes should mean something. In some sense here serialization might actually just be calling the same byte sequence by a different name, without actually carrying out any processing at all! In fact you may have witnessed this if you've ever opened up a binary file in a text editor, or opened an incorrectly-encoded (or interpretation of encoding) web page. So if you are talking about a different in performance, well, comparing a 0-step operation to a n-step operation produces an obvious answer.

That said, C++ serialization may ironically happen to ultimately convert to a string, who knows, you are not supposed to know, it is up to indexedDB C++ implementations to decide this and abstract it away from you and hide its complexity. There are all types of other issues with efficient storing a bunch of bytes that extend well beyond serialization performance.

To summarize, serialization has a different meaning in C++ than what JSON.stringify means in Javascript. Converting a value to a string in js would only serve to slow down your program. Let indexedDB take care of that concern for you.

Comment: I commented on the original question. I'm not observing this behaviour at all for a large object. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't appreciate this answer as much as I should've when you first provided it because I didn't know enough. I've been working on an extension passing data to a native application in C compiled with SQLIte, and need to store that data in some form. The browser passes the C app only the message length as a uint32_t and a JSON string. Now, I can more clearly see what you were talking about here and it has become a lot more interesting also, not only in terms of storage form but also memory usage. Thanks again for taking the time to answer this question.